# Remove all other 'vote' links after a user votes for a candidate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building a simple voting thingy that'll appear in the sidebar of a college's website. The way it work's is simple. You pick who you like and that's it. It's structured like below. There's a `heading`, `sub-heading` and then `candidates`. Next to each `candidate` is the `like` link.

I'm stuck here: When a user clicks a `like` link, if what happens in `demo.php` is successful, then all the other `like` links for that `sub-heading` need to be taken out, so the user cannot vote for anyone else under that `sub-heading` anymore.

How can something like this be done when it's all built this way. If the `</div>` of `id=h2` were moved below all the `like`, it'll make thing easier I feel.

I'm willing to implement changes since this is just being built.

**Here's my demo.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar voting thingy</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".like").click(function() {
        var hasLike = $(this).data("id");
        var data = 'id='+hasLike;
        console.log($(this).data('id'));

        if(hasLike) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"demo.php",
                data:data,
                beforeSend:function(html){
                    // We'll think of something to do here
                },
                success: function(page_data){
                    // Remove the remaining like links. How?
                    $('.like[data-id="'+page_data+'"]').append(page_data);
                },
                error: function(page_data){
                    $("#errors").empty();
                    $("#errors").fadeIn(200);
                    $("#errors").append('Screwed up!');
                },
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="h1" data-id="1">Teachers</div>
        <div id="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher?</div>
            <div>* Homer Simpson &nbsp  <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="3" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Elmer Fudd &nbsp     <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="4" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Bugs Bunny &nbsp     <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="5" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Obelix &nbsp         <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="6" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Mojo Jojo &nbsp      <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="7" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
        <br>
    <div id="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants</div>
        <div id="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town?</div>
            <div>* McDonalds &nbsp              <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="10" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* KFC &nbsp                    <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="11" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* The Heart Attack Grill &nbsp <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="12" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* In-n-Out &nbsp               <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="13" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>
            <div>* Popeye's &nbsp               <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="14" data-sec="9">Like</span></div>

    <div id="errors" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here's demo.php *(nothing much in here for now)***

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo $_GET['id'];
} else {
    echo 'Error! Id not found';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: it is not valid to have a duplicate ID! your h2 and h3s should be classes

Second: change your `.click` function to `on()`

```
$(".like").on('click', function() { ... };
```

at the end of your click function do that:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('.like').off();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you just need to have a class to go back "up the tree" to, and then drill down again.

For example, let's restructure your HTML a bit, it's incorrectly indented and a bit messy.

```
<h1 data-id="1">Teachers</h1>
<div class="sub-heading">
    <h2 data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher?</h2>
    <div>* Homer Simpson &nbsp  <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="3" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
    <div>* Elmer Fudd &nbsp     <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="4" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
    <div>* Bugs Bunny &nbsp     <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="5" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
    <div>* Obelix &nbsp         <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="6" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
    <div>* Mojo Jojo &nbsp      <span id="h3" class="like" data-id="7" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
</div>
```

The above looks like a "list" to me, so semantically you should think about swapping all those `<div>`'s out for a `<ul>` and a bunch of `<li>`'s.

Now that we have our `.sub-heading` class container which has this group of sub elements, they're an easy target.

```
$(".like").click(function() {
    var hasLike = $(this).data("id");
    var data = 'id='+hasLike;
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
    var $this = $(this); // <-- Set a reference to this element

    if(hasLike) {
        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"demo.php",
            data:data,
            beforeSend:function(html){
                // We'll think of something to do here
            },
            success: function(page_data){
                // Remove the remaining like links. How?

                $this.closest('.sub-heading').find('.like').remove();
                // Notice we're using the reference we set earlier
                // Then we're going back "up the tree" to the closest .sub-heading
                // Drilling down again, finding all the .like elements
                // And simply removing them

                $('.like[data-id="'+page_data+'"]').append(page_data);
            },
            error: function(page_data){
                $("#errors").empty();
                $("#errors").fadeIn(200);
                $("#errors").append('Screwed up!');
            },
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
$('.like').click( function() {
    $('.like').hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UPGKR/)